# (Jupyterlab) Matplotlib plot shows correct size only after double clicking the image of the plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

I have two dataframes (`usa` and `gdf`) and I am trying to plot and label/annotate the image using `geopandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep   

ax = gdf.plot(markersize=15, figsize=(20, 100))

#plot boundary of the USA map
usa.geometry.boundary.plot(color=None,edgecolor='k',linewidth = 1, ax = ax)
 
# Plot some number at certain point coordinate (latitude, longitude)
for x, y, label in zip(tqdm(gdf.geometry.x), gdf.geometry.y, gdf.n):
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(x, y), fontsize= 10, color = 'red')
    sleep(0.1) 

# Annotate text: country name at a point coordinate (centroid)
usa.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text = x.NAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', fontsize= 8,color='black',weight='bold'),axis=1);

# set the limit of the axis because original axis is large
# ax.axis('off')
plt.xlim([-140,-60])
plt.ylim([15,55])
plt.savefig("state.png", pad_inches = 0, format = 'png')
```

This is what I get [image]

Now, when I double click the image, I can see the enlarged version like below:
[image]

**Question 1: How to get the proper image in notebook without the need to double click**

---

When I open this image on my system, there is a lot of grey space like show below:
[image]

**Question 2: How to save the image with no grey area**

---

**Interesting Part**

When I remove the line

```
usa.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text = x.NAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', fontsize= 8,color='black',weight='bold'),axis=1);
```

I see the image in the notebook clearly (without double clicking) as shown below:
[image]

though image saved on system still has the grey areas.I can decrease the height of the `figsize` but grey area still exists in saved image

I'd appreciate some help in figure out the image size and save option.

Comment: In your code, `figsize=(20, 100)` is the cause of having very tall image of 20x100 size. Try better number, for example, (20,10).

Comment: Changing height doesn't remove the greyline check issues